# When importing a module via github into a notebook, how can I get the sub modules to import also?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

I'm playing with a library and am doing this in my colab notebook:

```
!git clone https://github.com/ProjectDrawdown/solutions
```

this creates a folder called solutions in my root folder, then I do this -

```
# Import modules we'll use later
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '..')
from solutions.solution import factory
```

The root module imports but the sub ones do not.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b5d7e6c5ec59> in <module>
      4 # Import modules we'll use later
      5 import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '..')
----> 6 from solutions.solution import factory
      7 import pandas as pd
      8 import numpy as np

/content/solutions/solution/factory.py in <module>
      4 from pathlib import Path
      5 from functools import lru_cache
----> 6 from model import advanced_controls as ac
      7 from model import scenario
      8 from model import vma

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this? It would be nice to sometimes just import this via colab so I can quickly play with a git repo

Answer (score 0):

You can simply import all with:

```
from solutions.solution import *
```

Although do note that using import * in python programs is considered a bad habit because this way you are polluting your namespace, the import * statement imports all the functions and classes into your own namespace, which may clash with the functions you define or functions of other libraries that you import.

Comment: I just tried and I still got the same error. Are you saying to replace my import with the import * or should I add it first then import my modules?
First approach still gave me a import on factory..the second says factory not found when it's referenced later